# How to do a partial download of a gzip file in curl,wget,php?

Tags: php, curl, wget

all, i want to do partial download of a gzip file and save it in a folder. for ex i want to download only 100 k bytes of a file. I tried using curl -r option , but still not working.

Can anybody help me here.

Comment: You realise that you probably won't be able to unzip a partial zip file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ulimit`. The number is is 1024-byte blocks:

```
ulimit -f 100; wget http://google.com
```